# How to edit and change Junction link target paths in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, junction, mklink

I'm having a problem that appears to have stemmed from a fresh install of Windows 10. Somewhere during the install, user name "ars_n" must have been created. I researched how to change the User name from "ars_n" to "n8mdp" which I was successful at doing. Unfortunately, by doing this, I think it is messing up the junction links such that I can't install an older program that keeps looking for the directory "C:\Documents and Settings\n8mdp..". This was how Windows XP used to install programs. I checked the installation on other Windows 10 machines and it worked fine. So I'm convinced that it has to do with the Junction links. Using NTFSLinkView, I see the following:

Name: Application Data

Full Path: C:\Users\n8mdp\Application Data

Type: Junction

Target Path: C:\Users\ars_n\AppData\Roaming

I really think the 'ars_'n in the Target Path is what is preventing my software needed to install correctly.

Is there a clean way to edit the target path to change the 'ars_n' to 'n8mdp'? I absolutely can't afford to lose what is in the Roaming folder. I've been researching the use of mklink. I tried to delete the link and came up with errors. I'm hoping someone can help me and provide a simple way to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been resolved. The issue was Windows 10 Junction links that were not correct. I used the 'rmdir' command to remove the Path to Target, then used the 'mklink /J' command to recreate the link with the proper target path. Once that was changed, I was able to install the program.

Junction links can be a great tool if used correctly.